# Why does my dictionary creation for loop stop halfway Python

Tags: python, dictionary, for-loop

I am trying to a create dictionary which takes in the whole alphabet and uses each letter as a key and then for its value it uses the letter twice. I have written the below code:

```
import string
alphabet = list(string.ascii_lowercase)

main_dict = {}
for x in alphabet:
      key = alphabet.pop()
      value = key + key
      new_dict = dict.fromkeys(key, value)
      main_dict.update(new_dict) 
      print(main_dict)
```

This seems to work until I get to the letter N and then it stops iterating.

Here is what it outputs:

```
{'z': 'zz', 'y': 'yy', 'x': 'xx', 'w': 'ww', 'v': 'vv', 'u': 'uu', 't': 'tt', 's': 'ss', 'r': 'rr', 'q': 'qq', 'p': 'pp', 'o': 'oo', 'n': 'nn'}
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! If you're new to Python, you may also be glad to know value = key * 2 works as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### Problem

You iterate forward with `x` and you remove from the end with `key = alphabet.pop()` so when you arrived half-way, you have removed the 2nd half, so there is **nothing** to iterate on

Printing `x, key, alphabet` gives

```
a z ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k', 'l', 'm', 'n', 'o', 'p', 'q', 'r', 's', 't', 'u', 'v', 'w', 'x', 'y']
b y ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k', 'l', 'm', 'n', 'o', 'p', 'q', 'r', 's', 't', 'u', 'v', 'w', 'x']
c x ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k', 'l', 'm', 'n', 'o', 'p', 'q', 'r', 's', 't', 'u', 'v', 'w']
d w ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k', 'l', 'm', 'n', 'o', 'p', 'q', 'r', 's', 't', 'u', 'v']
```

#### Fix & improve

- use only `x` to read from the alphabet
- don't create an intermediate`new_dict`: add the mapping in `main_dict`
- you can iterate on the `str` `string.ascii_lowercase`, no need of a `list`

```
import string

main_dict = {}
for key in string.ascii_lowercase:
    main_dict[key] = key * 2
```

---

The `dict-comprehension` version is

```
main_dict = {key: key * 2 for key in string.ascii_lowercase}
```

Comment: can also do it like this: `main_dict.update({key: key+key})`

Comment: Thank you! just curious when using .pop you mention that after getting halfway through there is nothing left, do you know why this is? Sorry if that is a stupid question..

Comment: @Douet the method `pop` removes and return the last item

Answer (score 0):

It's because you are popping elements from the alphabet.  Do it like this:

```
import string

alphabet = list(string.ascii_lowercase)
main_dict = {}
for x in alphabet:
     main_dict[x] = x+x
     
print(main_dict)
```

Answer (score 0):

You're modifying the list while iteration (with `alphabet.pop()`, which lead to undesired behaviour - here stops at letter `N`). To get desired result, you can use dict-comprehension:

```py
import string

alphabet = string.ascii_lowercase

main_dict = {ch: ch * 2 for ch in alphabet}
print(main_dict)
```

Prints:

```
{'a': 'aa', 'b': 'bb', 'c': 'cc', 'd': 'dd', 'e': 'ee', 'f': 'ff', 'g': 'gg', 'h': 'hh', 'i': 'ii', 'j': 'jj', 'k': 'kk', 'l': 'll', 'm': 'mm', 'n': 'nn', 'o': 'oo', 'p': 'pp', 'q': 'qq', 'r': 'rr', 's': 'ss', 't': 'tt', 'u': 'uu', 'v': 'vv', 'w': 'ww', 'x': 'xx', 'y': 'yy', 'z': 'zz'}
```

Comment: The question seems to ask more of why the code isnt working. Though i like your approach at solving the problem, I dont think it answers OPs question

Comment: @MuhdMairaj Added.